# JavaScript/HTML text boxes; variables; need help correcting code/explanation as to why it's wrong

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox, output

I have to do text boxes that add up and multiply values together. I cant seem to get the code right, and I don't know where I went wrong. The first button 'Raw Total' works properly but none of the following buttons do. If somebody could edit the code and fix it for me, that'd be awesome. Also, if somebody could explain where I went wrong, that would also be very appreciated. Thanks!

EDITED CODE:

```
<script>

var price_cal = 60 ;
var price_rim = 150 ;
var price_bar = 25 ;
var njtax = .07 ;
var value_cal = 60*first ;
var value_rim = 150*second ;
var value_bar = 25*third ;
var total = (1+njtax)*((price_cal*value_cal)+(price_rim*value_rim)+(price_bar*value_bar)) ;

var discount ;
if (total<115) {total*=1 ; discount="No Discount" ; }
else if ((total<200 && total>115)) {total*=.95 ; discount="5% off total order" ; }
else if (total>200) {total*=.90 ; discount="10% off total order" ; }
total=total.toFixed(2) ;

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() 
{ 
var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value ;
var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value ; 
var third = document.getElementById("textbox3").value ;

var answer = parseFloat(first*price_cal)+parseFloat(second*price_rim)+parseFloat(third*price_bar) ;
var textbox4 = document.getElementById("textbox4") ;
 textbox4.value=answer ;

var drate =  parseFloat(discount) ; 
var textbox5= document.getElementById("textbox5") ;
 textbox5.value=drate ;

var amount = parseFloat(discount) ;
var textbox6= document.getElementById("textbox6") ;
textbox6.value=amount ;

var trate = parseFloat(njtax*answer) ;
var textbox7= document.getElementById("textbox7") ;
textbox7.value=trate ;

var net = parseFloat(answer)*parseFloat(1.07) ;
var textbox8= document.getElementById("textbox8") ;
 textbox8.value=net ;
```

}

```
</script>
```

How many calipers would you like to buy?
     
            
How many 18 inch rim sets would you like to buy? 
     
            
How many brake pads would you like to buy?

Comment: Javascript != Java in any way

Answer (score 0):

`textbox5.value= ____________ ;`

That's the first thing I see. You need to set the value of the text box to an actual variable or value. Also, not sure where `drate` is coming from, so if you could edit your post to include all revevant HTML, that may help me/others see any other errors that may be present.

Comment: I changed the ______ values, sorry. That was the code from my blank template that i had to edit still. And the drate is me trying to set a new variable. I'm very lost right now, I'm sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize, I just wanted to make sure your markup was correct. :)

`var value_cal = 1*item_cal ;
var value_rim = 1*item_rim ;
var value_bar = 1*item_bar ;`

Where are `item_cal`, `item_rim`, and `item_bar` defined at?

Also consider including ALL code inside myFunction() to avoid any potential scoping issues.

Comment: the "item_example" tags were a part of my last assignment that i no longer needed. I didn't even realize they were still in there. however, they were defined as:         var item_cal = prompt("How many calipers do you wish to purchase at $60 each?" , "# of calipers") ;
 var item_rim = prompt("How many sets of 18 inch rims (2) do you wish to purchase at $150 each?" , "# of rim sets") ;
 var item_bar = prompt("How many handlebars you wish to purchase at $25 each" , "# of handlebars") ;  Also, i don't know what you mean by that last part. I just started learning java a couple weeks ago. Im new

Comment: Ah, so instead of using prompts, you are now using text boxes to receive those values. That is where one of the errors is happening. I'd suggest revisiting how you are reusing your code...

Comment: I changed those "item" tags to "price" tags. And now the tax text box is working. I'll edit the code to what i have currently @ToxicPineapple